# Bootstrap Col class not working correctly

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please have a look at

```css
.colName {
             text-align: center;
         }

         .calbox {
             border: 1px solid #999;
             padding: 5px;
             min-height: 40px;
         }   

        .Box1 {
            padding: 5px !important;
            margin: 1px 2px 0px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa4a4 !important;
            font-size: .95em;
            line-height: 1.3;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #000 !important;
        }

        .Box1_a {
            cursor: pointer !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: #000 !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 1</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 2</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox" style="height:200px;">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 3</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 4</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 5</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Why **Name 3** section didn't start just below **Name 1**, why there is space (i think because of extra height in **Name 2**).

Can you please guide me how to show **Name 3** just after **Name 1**.
Well Let me clear 1 thing, name would be name 100, so can't put negative margin to name 3 or any other because it is all dynamic.

I am also attaching the screenshot of html result.
[image]

Comment: you are following `row` approach, this is how it  has to behave. for your desired scenario use `column` approach

Comment: @DeepakYadav can you please guide me where to change ?

Answer (score 2):

Hi you are facing this problem because of uneven height of siblings.

Here I used masonry for output exactly you want: https://codepen.io/ShubhamAshish/pen/rrzRmo

```
$('.row-fluid').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.col-xs-6.col-md-3',
});
```

[image]

Comment: hmmm seems like it will work :) let me put in my code !

Comment: Looks good, +1, and don't forget to mention that one need to add the Masonry library

Comment: Yup :) Thanks @LGSon for guidence.


I added the things in codepen. So, if someone  download the pen he/she can get all the stuff. :)

Comment: @Shubham well it works with my given HTML :) but it is not working in project, because it is conflict with other jqueries :( .. is there any other option special with CSS or HTML. Thanks for your great response!

Comment: If you are already using jquery, then you need to add only https://unpkg.com/masonry-layout@4.2.0/dist/masonry.pkgd.min.js

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to do a markup change, place them columns wise, the odd numbered in 1 column, and the even in another.

```css
.colName {
             text-align: center;
         }

         .calbox {
             border: 1px solid #999;
             padding: 5px;
             min-height: 40px;
         }   

        .Box1 {
            padding: 5px !important;
            margin: 1px 2px 0px;
            border: 1px solid #aaa4a4 !important;
            font-size: .95em;
            line-height: 1.3;
            border-radius: 3px;
            font-weight: normal;
            color: #000 !important;
        }

        .Box1_a {
            cursor: pointer !important;
            text-decoration: none !important;
            color: #000 !important;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 1</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 3</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 5</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 2</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox" style="height:200px;">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colName"><b>Name 4</b></div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        28th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">28</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        29th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">29</div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 colFS Mon">
                        30th Nov
                        <div class="calbox">30</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: wow , I didn't read your full reply, just click on run and you resolve my problem, Thanks, and now let me read it :D

Comment: Oh no no, you change all the html :) well i edit the question, it all generated dynamically, with the HTML pattern same for all names.

Comment: @user2972061 Updated my answer to _If you are able to do a markup change,..._. Now it at least will be a viable option for you, or anyone else, who can make that change :)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can not have the desired results with bootstrap natively. You will need to use jquery lib for this or alter the HTML layout to trick the grid system.

When you use bootstrap, it gives the columns a property of float. Float will align the elements horizontally and name 3 will never float up to cover the white space.

jQuery way:
You can use https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/packery.html

HTML way:
The other way of doing this would be have a different HTML layout. Something like this:

```
<div class="cont">
  <div class="col1 col-xs-6">
   <div class="name1 col-xs-12 col-md-6"></div>
   <div class="name3 col-xs-12 col-md-6"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="col2 col-xs-6">
   <div class="name2 col-xs-12 col-md-6"></div>
   <div class="name4 col-xs-12 col-md-6"></div>
</div>
```

I wont recommend this type of html layout because if you change the height of any name block, then you will have to alter the HTML again.

I hope this helps.